# What about a branch on Stack Exchange for temporal/trend based questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, migration, asking-questions

Many questions along the lines of

- "which is the best X, amongst competitors",
- "what are the features of X"

… and other similar questions get removed from Stack Exchange sites; justifiably as well.

Users then must go either to chat or look on blogs, other forums, or review sites for answers or alternative opinions.

Having questions that can later become redundant of course do not belong on the sites, but I was wondering if some accommodation can be made as an assistance? I can imagine that some solution can be devised to include these queries. Maybe not in the main trunk of a site, but in a blog-like branch?

That is just a random possibility that comes to mind.

Answer (score 2):

There are definitely initiatives to support a blog-based arm of many sites:

see

http://blogoverflow.com

and

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/

Comment: Would a blog for Stack Overflow ever be considered. I realise there currently [is one](http://blog.stackoverflow.com) but it really has nothing to do with programming articles and more to do with day-to-day operations of Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: I looked at the blogs, but they are really just blogs and do not contain the features that made SE great-reputation/badges/linking abilities/questioning. In general it is a normal blog sphere. It lacks the great/brilliant SE features.

Comment: I do not understand why there are down votes for this question, and there are no comments about why these votes were cast. A large number of users post questions of this sort and have these questions closed. It is a normal/logical question to ask.

Comment: @vass this request is an OK one, but there are a lot of ways it could go wrong. The blog outcome is best, but would take discipline.